# Make Color overlayed widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make an widget that looks like Color overlay is applied on widget. see the below image of spotify app. you can see the bottom navigation bar has top portion as a transparent and bottom portion has black color. and when you scroll it you can feel it. but I want on all four sides of widget rather than only top and bottom. how can I do it.

[Here is the Image of Spotify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ham9B.jpg)
[Here is the Image that I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXb31.png) (that blur grey color at borders)

Previously I have tried it but that is using `ShaderMask` and that is applied only for top and bottom portion only.

```dart
ShaderMask(
  shaderCallback: (Rect rect) {
  return const LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    colors: [Colors.white, Colors.transparent, Colors.transparent, Colors.white],
    stops: [0.0, 0.03, 0.99, 1.0],
  ).createShader(rect);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried (add HTML and CSS) and what is your one challenge with that?

Comment: check https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter_vignettes/blob/master/vignettes/_shared/lib/ui/widget_mask.dart#L56

Comment: @pskink I have updated this post with second Image. may you get some idea about what I want to do.

Comment: and have you already tried `BackdropFilter` / `ImageFiltered` with `ImageFilter.blur` filter?

Comment: @pskink not yet